# How to do semantic segmentation using yolov2 in python3.7?

Tags: python, yolo, semantic-segmentation

I labeled images with bounding box and then used yolov2 (python 3.7) for object detection and It was successful (https://github.com/deep-diver/Soccer-Ball-Detection-YOLOv2/blob/master/YOLOv2-Train.ipynb). I need to use yolov2 for semantic segmentation using python. Which image-labeling software can I use for semantic segmentation which its output is compatible with yolo? How can I modify the code in the aforementioned website to use yolov2 for this matter? Or do we have any example for that?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Abbas,

Answer (score 0):

None of the YOLO algorithms perform Semantic Segmentation. They are Object Detection algorithms. In your case, you can use any of the following algorithms for segmentation: DeepLab, UNet, PSPNet, EfficientNet, etc.

Comment: I found "Mask R-CNN" for semantic segmentation. Any idea bout this method? Thanks,

Comment: Remember, Mask RCNN and YOLACT/YOLACT++ are instance segmentation models and not semantic segmentation. Both the architectures are quite complex, especially the Mask RCNN. If you're starting in this field, I would suggest you to look at the models I had mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can use YOLACT/YOLACT++ https://github.com/dbolya/yolact It uses same labelme annotations and you just have to edit the cofig.py a little and you will get the desired results. I am using it and it is superb.

Yolact is a kind of transformation of YOLO and it means You Look at the Coefficient.

Comment: Hi Areeb, Thank you for your help. I will use YOLACT for semantic segmentation.

Comment: YOLACT is indeed a very good model but I wouldn't advise it for someone who's starting their journey in semantic segmentation.